# MongoDB: WriteConflict error: this operation conflicted with another operation. Please retry your operation or multi-document transaction

Tags: mongodb

Getting **WriteConflict error frequently** when calling an **api in parallel(4 times)** that does **new inserts of  batchsize of 10K docs in a transaction**. But if the **insert batchsize is set to 2K** it runs fine. not sure which parameter I need to adjust so that insertion works without issue for 10k batchsize

**MongoDB server version: 4.4.0**

Not sure if this has sth to do with this https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-53464

Here is the mongo log for same when mongo loglevel set to 1

```
    {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-23T17:23:40.838+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn42","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"mydb.mycollection","command":{"insert":"mycollection","ordered":false,"$db":"mydb","lsid":{"id":{"$uuid":"a0beb5f8-ed4c-4b64-8971-719178b3a598"}},"$clusterTime":{"clusterTime":{"$timestamp":{"t":1611422612,"i":10000}},"signature":{"hash":{"$binary":{"base64":"H3DsiEiy4CMrRNvWqbIJQMbHl0c=","subType":"0"}},"keyId":6870929147875557381}},"txnNumber":4,"startTransaction":true,"autocommit":false},"ninserted":10000,"keysInserted":30000,"numYields":0,"reslen":230,"locks":{},"storage":{"data":{"bytesRead":1661221,"timeReadingMicros":3201739}},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":3741}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-23T17:23:40.838+00:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"QUERY",    "id":22790,   "ctx":"conn42","msg":"Received interrupt request for unknown op","attr":{"opId":28178}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-23T17:23:40.909+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"TXN",      "id":51802,   "ctx":"conn42","msg":"transaction","attr":{"parameters":{"lsid":{"id":{"$uuid":"a0beb5f8-ed4c-4b64-8971-719178b3a598"},"uid":{"$binary":{"base64":"Zx/+1Rn/RW/eLwwG9xqjQAzGuq4fRkYljdz5CIhAbaw=","subType":"0"}}},"txnNumber":4,"autocommit":false,"readConcern":{"provenance":"implicitDefault"}},"readTimestamp":"Timestamp(0, 0)","ninserted":10000,"keysInserted":30000,"terminationCause":"aborted","timeActiveMicros":3810904,"timeInactiveMicros":2702,"numYields":0,"locks":{"ReplicationStateTransition":{"acquireCount":{"w":2}},"Global":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Database":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Collection":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Mutex":{"acquireCount":{"r":46}}},"storage":{"data":{"bytesRead":1661221,"timeReadingMicros":3201739}},"wasPrepared":false,"durationMillis":3813}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-23T17:23:40.910+00:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22411,   "ctx":"conn42","msg":"Slow WT transaction. Lifetime of SnapshotId {getSnapshotId_toNumber} was {transactionTime}ms","attr":{"getSnapshotId_toNumber":78620,"transactionTime":3813}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-23T17:23:40.933+00:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"COMMAND",  "id":21962,   "ctx":"conn42","msg":"Assertion while executing command","attr":{"command":"commitTransaction","db":"admin","commandArgs":{"commitTransaction":1,"$db":"admin","lsid":{"id":{"$uuid":"a0beb5f8-ed4c-4b64-8971-719178b3a598"}},"$clusterTime":{"clusterTime":{"$timestamp":{"t":1611422620,"i":10000}},"signature":{"hash":{"$binary":{"base64":"+r9TOIIR/J8dXRvrPyF0urUeWJA=","subType":"0"}},"keyId":6870929147875557381}},"txnNumber":4,"autocommit":false},"error":"WriteConflict: WriteConflict error: this operation conflicted with another operation. Please retry your operation or multi-document transaction."}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-23T17:23:40.933+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn42","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"admin.$cmd","command":{"commitTransaction":1,"$db":"admin","lsid":{"id":{"$uuid":"a0beb5f8-ed4c-4b64-8971-719178b3a598"}},"$clusterTime":{"clusterTime":{"$timestamp":{"t":1611422620,"i":10000}},"signature":{"hash":{"$binary":{"base64":"+r9TOIIR/J8dXRvrPyF0urUeWJA=","subType":"0"}},"keyId":6870929147875557381}},"txnNumber":4,"autocommit":false},"numYields":0,"ok":0,"errMsg":"WriteConflict error: this operation conflicted with another operation. Please retry your operation or multi-document transaction.","errName":"WriteConflict","errCode":112,"reslen":394,"locks":{"ReplicationStateTransition":{"acquireCount":{"w":3}},"Global":{"acquireCount":{"r":1,"w":1}},"Database":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Collection":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Mutex":{"acquireCount":{"r":46}}},"flowControl":{"acquireCount":1,"timeAcquiringMicros":1},"storage":{},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":93}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-23T17:23:40.933+00:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"QUERY",    "id":22790,   "ctx":"conn42","msg":"Received interrupt request for unknown op","attr":{"opId":28235}}
```

Comment: That jira ticket you linked specifically says it only affects versions 4.4.x, can you test with an older version?

Comment: Use the documented transaction API.

Comment: @D.SM care to explain what is documented transaction API?

Comment: @Joe yep, will also run some tests on older mongodb 4.2.x version when I can

Comment: Did you find a way to solve the issue?

Comment: @b.ben Not sure what's the root cause but decreasing the batch count was the only solution that I found.

Comment: @Joe experiencing the same with Mongo 4.11.0.

Answer (score 2):

From the mongodb transaction docs:

Number of operations in a transaction:
There are no hard limits to the number of documents that can be read within a transaction. As a best practice, no more than 1,000 documents should be modified within a transaction.

For operations that need to modify more than 1,000 documents, developers should break the transaction into separate parts that process documents in batches.

Comment: Thanks. That's best practice -- I would read it as if using larger than 1K batchsize then it will slow down the operation but would not throw error.
I am trying to understand what is causing WriteConflict error

Answer (score -1):

You may have missed putting `await` in an `async` task; e.g.,

```
await place.remove({ session: sess });
```

Answer (score -1):

That log shows that the transaction is taking 3.7 seconds to insert 10k documents, due to the disk taking 3.2 seconds to read 1.6M bytes.

You might try improving the hardware or reducing the transaction size so there is less opportunity for a conflicting operation to occur.